# Unable to pass data from HTML Form as JSON

Tags: html, json, forms

I'm trying to achieve below result using simple HTML form:

```
{"name": "Abc","email": "abc@abc.org", "message":"msg"}
```

HTML code:

```
<form name = "myform" action="URL" method="POST" enctype="application/json">
<input type="hidden" name="name" value="Abc">
<input type="hidden" name="email" value="Abc@abc.org">
<input type="hidden" name="message" value="msg">
<input type ="submit" value="Submit"> 
</form>
```

But this doesn't work. Someone suggested to use below and it worked but not sure how it is encoding data into JSON format.

```
<form name = "myform" action="URL" method="POST" enctype="text/plain">
<input type="hidden" name='{"name":"Abc","email":"abc@abc.org","message":"'value='msg"}'>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"> 
</form>
```

Can someone please explain how the above works? Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

The [`enctype` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-enctype) simply has no option to encode as JSON.

There was [a proposal](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-json-forms/) to add support, but it was abandoned.

`text/plain` encodes the data in a plain text format which is **not reliably machine parsable** (e.g. you can't distinguish between a new line as data and a new line as a record separator). You should never use it in production. It was designed as a debugging tool but, frankly, having software that can display parsed `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data is more useful for that.

The code you have "works" because the plain text format just concatenates the names and values, one per line, and you have half a JSON text in the name and the other half in the value.

It's very fragile, and would be more so if the user was inputting any data themselves.

Comment: A descriptive answer but I'm unable to understand you last 2 lines which is the sole purpose of this question.

Comment: Which don't you understand about them?

Comment: "The code you have "works" because the plain text format just concatenates the names and values, one per line, and you have half a JSON text in the name"

Comment: What, precisely don't you understand about that? Quoting an entire paragraph back doesn't really help.

Comment: see we are not doing any encoding here( enctype is text/plain). So when we say half of the JSON is in the name and half in the value, then how is that happening. Sorry i may sound foolish but i'm new to this tech

Comment: You explicitly put half the JSON in the name attribute and half the JSON in the value attribute.